# Theano ImportError: cannot import name inplace_increment

Tags: python-2.7, theano, conda

I've installed Theano as such:

```
(python2) bash-3.2$ sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

I'm using conda with Python 2.7. The `python2` in parentheses is my conda environment. I'm trying to run the code from iGAN: https://github.com/junyanz/iGAN. I'm on OS X 10.11.6.

The error I get is `ImportError: cannot import name inplace_increment`. I've tried manually removing the Theano cache (as described in https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5564) and the same error still arises. (I can't use `theano-cache purge` because it requires installing a version of scipy that clashes with the version required by OpenCV.) I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Theano via pip and still get the same error. Any suggestions?

Here's the context:

```
(python2) bash-3.2$ python iGAN_main.py 
//anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:254: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a record
array. This code will likely break in the next numpy release --
see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
  ai = a.__array_interface__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iGAN_main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import constrained_opt
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/Code/iGAN/constrained_opt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib.rng import np_rng
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/Code/iGAN/lib/rng.py", line 2, in <module>
    from theano.sandbox.rng_mrg import MRG_RandomStreams as RandomStreams
  File "//anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "//anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "//anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 60, in <module>
    from theano import tensor, scalar
  File "//anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.tensor.subtensor import *
  File "//anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/subtensor.py", line 27, in <module>
    from cutils_ext.cutils_ext import inplace_increment
ImportError: cannot import name inplace_increment
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.

Deleting the cache manually worked.

```
rm -rf ~/.theano
```

If that doesn't help try installing from source.

```
python setup.py install
```